# How can I make text option appear depending on radio in opencart?

Tags: text, checkbox, opencart

In Opencart I have 2 options: a textarea input, where the user enters some text; and a radio, where the user selects if he wants or not to enter some text for the product. If text is selected then I want the text option to be displayed or to make it required, if the text option can't be hidden.

Is there anyway I can achieve that ?

```
<div id="option-297" class="option">
<span class="required">*</span>
<b>Checkbox:</b><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[297][]" value="106" id="option-value-106" />
        <label for="option-value-106">Without text</label>
<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[297][]" value="105" id="option-value-105" />
        <label for="option-value-105">With text</label>
<br />
```

```
<div id="option-237" class="option">
<b>Text:</b>
<br />
    <textarea name="option[237]" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<br />
```

Comment: This is on the product page? Can you please provide a code snippet for the fields in question?

Comment: Added the code :) Sorry